How can I protect exposed bolt threads outdoors?
I installed some concrete anchors into my block wall for the recent hurricane to board up my windows.  I'd like to leave the bolts in the wall (because it makes it really easy for a single person to put the boards up), but I'm concerned that if I leave them exposed, the weather will make the threads unusable in short order.
So, I need some type of sealant to protect them, but it has to be able to come back off again later when I need to use them, and whatever I use needs to be able to withstand direct Florida sunshine in the summer without melting (which is why I can't use a simple grease or wax).
Any ideas?

If you haven't already, you should probably put a zinc washer and nut on the anchor bolt while it sits empty on the wall (with a bit of zinc spray beforehand). Snug the nut up well. This will keep the anchor engaged and ready for when you board up and put another nut on.

Anti-seize compound?

Galvanized bolts will last quite some time before corroding. You can add zinc spray when you see that the galvanization is starting to disappear. Zinc spray will form a thin film that will be easily removed by the nut - so you should re-apply regularly after use.
If it's black steel without any protection, it will corrode in short order. Zinc spray may delay it.
In addition SS316 bolts exists. They need no protection, and will never corrode. On the other hand, SS316 is rather susceptible to galling.

Yeah, they're already installed, so it's a bit late to be choosing a material.  According to the spec, these are "carbon steel", so I don't expect them to last long without some kind of protection.

No zinc plating or galvanizing? If so add zinc spray. Note that the material will be carbon steel; plating is specified in addition to the base material. Unplated carbon steel is extremely uncommon, as it will quickly corrode in almost any environment.

It's this one here: https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-8-in-x-5-in-Parawedge-Anchor-1-Pack-499NS/312751407
It says it's "made in two materials" which I thought were options, but maybe it's listing core & plating?  If so, then the plating would be 304 stainless steel.

I can't access the link (blocked outside US), but if it says SS304 it's a reasonably good steel, which won't rust. It's not plating; the bolt is made from 304. In a very salty and humid atmosphere it will develop pitting in the long term.

Strangely, the packaging makes no mention of material and the website says: "More than 39 sizes are available, in two types of material: Carbon steel and 304 Stainless steel."  So... yeah, unclear.
Thank you, though, I'll give the zinc spray a shot.  That sounds like the right answer.

Zinc spray will not affect 304 negatively, and works wonders on carbon steel. One test is to use a magnet. Carbon steel is strongly magnetic, 304 is weakly magnetic, and 316 is not magnetic at all.

Just to confirm, the link above points to a carbon steel product. Zinc spray good.

@jsotola Really?  Because both the packaging and website say interior/exterior.

@Louis I misunderstood the webpage

Put plastic cap nuts and rubber washers on the ends of the bolts use plenty of anti-seize or grease.
The nut will protect the threads, the washer will keep water out and the grease also help to prevent corrosion.
If the plastic nut gets stuck it can be crushed with pliers to loosen it.
Use metal nuts to fasten the storm shutters.

When I lived in Florida (SE portion of the coast).  I too had anchors into the concrete block of the walls.  The box of bolts was kept inside until needed.  If you leave those bolts outside, who knows what condition they will be in when you need to board up.  If for some reason you need the bolts in the wall just prior to putting up the plywood or whatever, you can always insert them then immediately put up the plywood boards.
My full recommendation would be to keep a box of needed hardware inside, ready to use.  The hardware kit includes a few extra bolts just in case. It might not be a bad idea to have the right size tap for your bolts as well as a can of some sort of oil/lubricant in your emergency kit. A few extra anchors would be worth having as well.  By tap, I mean the thing that can clean up machine screws.  If your bolts are lag screws, you wouldn't need a tap.  If your anchors are parawedge, that's a different animal.  In that case your kit should include the lubricant, a few extra parawedge bolts and whatever is necessary to insert them.   Also in your kit would be the approprite die to clean the threads instead of a tap.
I would not put the nut on the bolt, keep the nuts in your kit.  You don't have time to deal with a frozen nut when a hurricane is about to show up.  The die will clean the threads.  Remember, things like PB Blaster and Liquid Wrench need time to soak into the frozen threads. Neither time nor a hardware store are available in such a situation.
In the off season (January in Florida maybe) - make a practice run of some of your emergency connections.

In this case, I'm using parawedge concrete anchors, so the anchor is the bolt.  These bolts are not designed to be removed easily, hence why I'd rather just protect them.

The thing you need to clean up bolt threads is a "die" not a "tap"  (taps are to clean up or form nut threads)
